# To check whether Table is empty or not

Tags: ruby, watir

In WATIR, I could write the code $browser.table(:id,'something') to manipulate table, Now I would  like to check whether this table is empty or not? How would I do that?

Comment: What does empty mean? If it has a tr?

Comment: Except header row, everyother row should not contain any value is what I call empty.

Comment: Can you give HTML examples of a table that is and one that is not empty? Not containing a value is somewhat vague - eg is that no text, text fields are blank, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to lookup for the child nodes. And see if the count of the child nodes is 1 that is only the table headers are present. If it is more than one that means some data is present in the table otherwise the table is empty.

For Example:

If you have a table with id="something"

```
document.getElementById("something").childNodes.length
```

The childNodes property returns a NodeList containing the child nodes of the selected node.
If the selected node has no children, this property returns a NodeList containing no nodes.

You may refer [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_childnodes.asp) page

Comment: "document.getElementById("something").childNodes.length"

I am asking for WATIR Code not Java Script code.

Comment: sorry overlooked that

Comment: Not a problem, If you know Ruby solution, just let me know.